# PostgreSQL Query - Solution

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have table

```
                                                 Table "public.queue_calendar"
     Column     |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Compression | Stats target | Description 
----------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 day_of_week    | character varying(10)  |           | not null |         | extended |             |              | 
 time_slot      | time without time zone |           | not null |         | plain    |             |              | 
 total_slots    | integer                |           |          |         | plain    |             |              | 
 occupied_slots | integer                |           |          |         | plain    |             |              | 
Indexes:
    "queue_calendar_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (day_of_week, time_slot)
Access method: heap
```

with the data (cropped days)

```
 day_of_week | time_slot | total_slots | occupied_slots 
-------------+-----------+-------------+----------------
 Monday      | 08:30:00  |          10 |              0
 Monday      | 09:00:00  |          10 |              0
 Monday      | 09:30:00  |          10 |              0
 Monday      | 10:00:00  |          10 |              0
 Monday      | 10:30:00  |          10 |              0
 Monday      | 11:00:00  |          10 |              0
 Monday      | 11:30:00  |          10 |              0
 Monday      | 12:00:00  |          10 |              0
 Monday      | 12:30:00  |          10 |              0
 Monday      | 13:00:00  |          10 |              0
 Monday      | 13:30:00  |          10 |              0
 Monday      | 14:00:00  |          10 |              0
 Monday      | 14:30:00  |          10 |              0
 Monday      | 15:00:00  |          10 |              0
 Monday      | 15:30:00  |          10 |              0
 Monday      | 16:00:00  |          10 |              0
 Monday      | 16:30:00  |          10 |              0
 Monday      | 17:00:00  |          10 |              0
 Monday      | 17:30:00  |          10 |              0
 Monday      | 18:00:00  |          10 |              0
 Monday      | 18:30:00  |          10 |              0
 Monday      | 19:00:00  |          10 |              0
 Monday      | 19:30:00  |          10 |              0
 Monday      | 20:00:00  |          10 |              0
 Monday      | 20:30:00  |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 08:30:00  |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 09:00:00  |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 09:30:00  |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 10:00:00  |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 10:30:00  |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 11:00:00  |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 11:30:00  |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 12:00:00  |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 12:30:00  |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 13:00:00  |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 13:30:00  |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 14:00:00  |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 14:30:00  |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 15:00:00  |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 15:30:00  |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 16:00:00  |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 16:30:00  |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 17:00:00  |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 17:30:00  |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 18:00:00  |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 18:30:00  |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 19:00:00  |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 19:30:00  |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 20:00:00  |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 20:30:00  |          10 |              0
```

I have the query which extract all data for the current day where occupied_slots < total_slots (this one is work correctly) but when I try to make statement when current time is less than 12:00 - I should extract data for the NEXT day from 08:30

the data extracted but I don't understand why it was extracted from 10:00 (not from 08:30)

here is the SELECT statement

```
WITH current_time_slot AS (
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIME + interval '2 hour') BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN 
                DATE_TRUNC('HOUR', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + interval '2 hour')
            WHEN EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIME + interval '2 hour') BETWEEN 11 AND 29 THEN 
                DATE_TRUNC('HOUR', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + interval '2 hour') + INTERVAL '30 minutes'
            WHEN EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIME + interval '2 hour') BETWEEN 30 AND 40 THEN 
                DATE_TRUNC('HOUR', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + interval '2 hour')
            WHEN EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIME + interval '2 hour') BETWEEN 41 AND 59 THEN 
                DATE_TRUNC('HOUR', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + interval '2 hour') + INTERVAL '30 minutes'
            ELSE 
                NULL
        END AS start_time
)
SELECT 
    day_of_week,
    TO_CHAR(time_slot, 'HH24:MI') AS time_slot,
    total_slots,
    occupied_slots
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            day_of_week,
            time_slot,
            LEAD(time_slot) OVER (PARTITION BY day_of_week ORDER BY time_slot) AS next_time_slot,
            total_slots,
            occupied_slots
        FROM 
            queue_calendar,
            current_time_slot
        WHERE 
            (
                EXTRACT(DOW FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = 
                CASE 
                    WHEN CURRENT_TIME + interval '2 hour' < '12:00' THEN
                        CASE 
                            WHEN day_of_week = 'Monday' THEN 1
                            WHEN day_of_week = 'Tuesday' THEN 2
                            WHEN day_of_week = 'Wednesday' THEN 3
                            WHEN day_of_week = 'Thursday' THEN 4
                            WHEN day_of_week = 'Friday' THEN 5
                            WHEN day_of_week = 'Saturday' THEN 6
                            WHEN day_of_week = 'Sunday' THEN 0
                        END
                    ELSE
                        CASE 
                            WHEN day_of_week = 'Monday' THEN 0
                            WHEN day_of_week = 'Tuesday' THEN 1
                            WHEN day_of_week = 'Wednesday' THEN 2
                            WHEN day_of_week = 'Thursday' THEN 3
                            WHEN day_of_week = 'Friday' THEN 4
                            WHEN day_of_week = 'Saturday' THEN 5
                            WHEN day_of_week = 'Sunday' THEN 6
                        END
                END
            )
            AND (
                (
                    (CURRENT_TIME + interval '2 hour' < '12:00' AND time_slot >= current_time_slot.start_time::TIME)
                    OR 
                    (CURRENT_TIME + interval '2 hour' >= '12:00' AND time_slot >= '08:30')
                )
                AND occupied_slots < total_slots + 2
            )
    ) AS subquery
WHERE
    CURRENT_TIME < next_time_slot OR next_time_slot IS NULL
ORDER BY 
    day_of_week, time_slot;
```

could someone point me to the right direction to fix this

PS: here is the response

```
 day_of_week | time_slot | total_slots | occupied_slots 
-------------+-----------+-------------+----------------
 Tuesday     | 10:30     |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 11:00     |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 11:30     |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 12:00     |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 12:30     |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 13:00     |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 13:30     |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 14:00     |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 14:30     |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 15:00     |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 15:30     |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 16:00     |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 16:30     |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 17:00     |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 17:30     |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 18:00     |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 18:30     |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 19:00     |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 19:30     |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 20:00     |          10 |              0
 Tuesday     | 20:30     |          10 |              0
(21 rows)
```

Comment: You add 2 hours ``DATE_TRUNC('HOUR', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + interval '2 hour')``. Then 08:30->10:30 as min time

Comment: @ValNik yeah. I have different time on the server so I added 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

fixed WHERE statement

from

```
WHERE
    CURRENT_TIME < next_time_slot OR next_time_slot IS NULL
ORDER BY 
    day_of_week, time_slot;
```

to

```
WHERE
    (
        (CURRENT_TIME + interval '2 hour' >= '20:11' AND time_slot >= '08:30')
        OR
        (CURRENT_TIME < next_time_slot OR next_time_slot IS NULL)
    )
ORDER BY 
day_of_week, time_slot;
```